# how to run a function using await for a certain amount of time

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  Future<dynamic> refreshState() async {
    setState(() {});
    await Future<dynamic>.delayed(animDuration + const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
    if (isPlaying) {
      await refreshState();
    }
  }
```

currently refreshState() is running non-stop. I want refreshState to run for 1 sec, then stop. I assume I need to set isPlaying = !isPlaying at some point but where?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you're looking for [Timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a count down parameter:

```
Future<dynamic> refreshState(int timeLeft) async {
    setState(() {});
    await Future<dynamic>.delayed(animDuration + const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
    if (isPlaying && timeLeft>0) {
      await refreshState(timeLeft-50);
    }
  }

....
refreshState(1000);
....
```